# Label regions with unique combinations of values in two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, python-2.6

I have two labelled 2D numpy arrays `a` and `b` with identical shapes. I would like to re-label the array `b` by something similar to a [GIS geometric union](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00080000000s000000) of the two arrays, such that **cells with unique combination of values in array `a` and `b` are assigned new unique IDs:**

[image]

I'm not concerned with the specific numbering of the regions in the output, so long as the values are all unique. I have attached sample arrays and desired outputs below: my real datasets are much larger, with both arrays having integer labels which range from "1" to "200000". So far I've experimented with concatenating the array IDs to form unique combinations of values, but ideally I would like to output a simple set of new IDs in the form of 1, 2, 3..., etc.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example labelled arrays a and b
input_a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
                    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
                    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
                    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
                    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
                    [0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
                    [0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

input_b = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

# Plot inputs
plt.imshow(input_a, cmap="spectral", interpolation='nearest')
plt.imshow(input_b, cmap="spectral", interpolation='nearest')

# Desired output, union of a and b
output = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

# Plot desired output
plt.imshow(output, cmap="spectral", interpolation='nearest')
```

Comment: I am trying to understand what you mean by union. What happed to all the values in the 2nd and 3rd rows of input_a in output which has all 0s in its corresponding rows?  Union is a set concept and would have size greater than or equal to any of the sets that form it. Extrapolating to arrays, the union of two arrays should be the same size or bigger than either, but that does not make sense as a set concept, so numpy.union1d reduces the dimensonality to 1.

Comment: Thanks Tris. I will revise the question to make things a little more clear: what I'm after is something similar to a union operation on GIS data, where two overlapping sets of polygons are broken up into smaller units based on the intersections of both inputs (http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00080000000s000000). In this case, I'm only interested in the regions which lie inside the area of array b, which is why my desired output is restricted to this extent.

Comment: @RobbiBishop-Taylor Are inputs `a` and `b` equal shaped?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, both `a` and `b` have identical shapes (as in the example data).

Comment: Then why not use arcpy.Union_analysis()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood the circumstances correctly, you are looking to have unique pairings from `a` and `b`. So, `1` from `a` and `1` from `b` would have one unique tag in the output; `1` from `a` and `3` from `b` would have another unique tag in the output. Also looking at the desired output in the question, it seems that there is an additional conditional situation here that if `b` is zero, the output is to be zero as well irrespective of the unique pairings.

The following implementation tries to solve all of that -

```
c = a*(b.max()+1) + b
c[b==0] = 0
_,idx = np.unique(c,return_inverse= True)
out = idx.reshape(b.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [21]: a
Out[21]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [22]: b
Out[22]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [23]: out
Out[23]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Sample plot -

```
# Plot inputs
plt.figure()                                                    
plt.imshow(a, cmap="spectral", interpolation='nearest')
plt.figure() 
plt.imshow(b, cmap="spectral", interpolation='nearest')

# Plot output
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(out, cmap="spectral", interpolation='nearest')
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if `a` has a region which does not overlap with any region in `b`. Wouldn't that lead to non-consecutive region IDs?

Comment: @miindlek Added few comments at the top, assuming certain more things. This is all based on what I could gather reading the question and looking at the desired output.

Comment: You interpreted the question correctly: this works almost exactly as I had hoped. There was one issue: the code generates incorrect outputs when run on arrays with large values (like my actual datasets with IDs up to 200000 mentioned above), as the first line of code `c = a*(b.max()+1) + b` can generate extremely large values (i.e. `200000*(200000+1)+200000`). I resolved this by setting the dtype of the input arrays to "np.int64".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it conceptually in terms of set union, but not to GIS geometric union, since that was mentioned after I answered.

Make a list of all possible unique 2-tuples of values with one from a and the other from b in that order. Map each tuple in that list to its index in it. Create the union array using that map.

For example say a and b are arrays each containing values in range(4) and assume for simplicity they have the same shape. Then:

```
v = range(4)
from itertools import permutations
p = list(permutations(v,2))
m = {}
for i,x in enumerate(p):
    m[x] = i
union = np.empty_like(a)
for i,x in np.ndenumerate(a):
    union[i] = m[(x,b[i])]
```

For demonstration, generating a and b with

```
np.random.randint(4, size=(3, 3))
```

produced:

```
a = array([[3, 0, 3],
           [1, 3, 2],
           [0, 0, 3]])

b = array([[1, 3, 1],
           [0, 0, 1],
           [2, 3, 0]])

m = {(0, 1): 0,
     (0, 2): 1,
     (0, 3): 2,
     (1, 0): 3,
     (1, 2): 4,
     (1, 3): 5,
     (2, 0): 6,
     (2, 1): 7,
     (2, 3): 8,
     (3, 0): 9,
     (3, 1): 10,
     (3, 2): 11}

union = array([[10,  2, 10],
               [ 3,  9,  7],
               [ 1,  2,  9]])
```

In this case the property that a union should be bigger or equal to its composits is reflected in increased numerical values rather than increase in number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

An issue with using itertools permutations is that the number of permutations could be much larger than needed. It would be much larger if the number of overlaps per area is much smaller than the number of areas.

The question uses *Union* but the picture shows an *Intersection*. Divakar's answer replicates the pictured *Intersection*, and is more elegant than my solution below, which produces the *Union*.

One could make a dictionary of only the actual overlaps, and then work from that. Flattening the input arrays first makes this easier for me to see, I'm not sure if that is feasible for you:

```
shp = numpy.shape(input_a)
a = input_a.flatten()
b = input_b.flatten()
s = set(((i,j) for i,j in zip(a,b)))           # unique pairings
d = {p:i for i,p in enumerate(sorted(list(s))} # dict{pair:index}
output_c = numpy.array([d[i,j] for i,j in zip(a,b)]).reshape(shp)

array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  2,  2,  4,  7,  7,  7,  7,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  2,  2,  4,  7,  7,  7,  7,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  6,  6,  6,  6,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  8,  9,  9,  9, 10,  6,  6,  6,  6,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  9,  9,  9, 10,  6,  6,  6,  6,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  9,  9,  9, 10,  6,  6,  6,  6,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```